# How will I create internal and external network interfaces, and assign IP addresses to them?

Tags: command-line, networking, virtualbox, ip, interface

I have 2 VMs (Ubuntu) installed in my VirtualBox. I want to do the following--

1. I want to set up two network interfaces: internal and external.
2. I want to assign IPv4 class C address for internal interface and B class address for external interface.

How will I do these ?

Scenario: One VM (VM1) will have the two network interfaces and also a firewall. Another VM (VM2) will be used for testing. VM2 will be considered as external network. VM1 will be considered as internal network.

How will I implement these?

Comment: I suggest you read through the networking part of VirtualBox help and familiarize yourself with the network settings.  https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html   Your comments in the answer below should be added to your question clarifying what it is that you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: i added to my question. please see.

Answer (score 0):

You must define the interfaces and subnets in Virtualbox not Ubuntu.  You can assign the individual interface parameters (like ip address for example) in your VMs.  In Virtual box use "internal network" for your internal and NAT, NAT network, or bridged adapter for the external facing ones.  Some of these will require an IP address on your host also.  NAT is the default.

Comment: One VM (VM1) will have the two network interfaces and also a firewall. Another VM (VM2) will be used for testing. 
How will I implement these?

Comment: VM2 will be considered as a external network

Comment: Now I am rethinking what it is you mean by "internal" and "external".  In Virtualbox, internal interfaces are for communication between Virtualbox VMs.  I need to understand what you mean by those terms but this is starting to sound more like a network design question.